# how to load outside application libraries into current application in cloud foundry bussiness application studio?

Tags: javascript, sapui5, cloud-foundry, sap-fiori

in my application i am using reuse libraries(fiori apps library) in neo environment(web ide). But i am planning to migrate my application in cloud foundry. so i am unable to load the libraries. In neo i am define the libraries in neo-app.json with type app name and loaded libraries same in component.js. By the way there is no index file and component files for reuse libraries in web ide. So how can i proceed/migrating here.

in my application i am using reuse libraries(fiori apps library) in neo environment(web ide). But i am planning to migrate my application in cloud foundry. so i am unable to load the libraries. In neo i am define the libraries in neo-app.json with type app name and loaded libraries same in component.js. By the way there is no index file and component files for reuse libraries in web ide. So how can i proceed